# FreeBSD nginx.pid Permission Denied

Tags: nginx, freebsd

Fresh install of nginx on FreeBSD 11.0_RELEASE.  Default nginx.conf with one mod to comment out the pid.  See the conf below.  The error:

```
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Default nginx.conf:

```
# user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

# This default error log path is compiled-in to make sure configuration parsing
# errors are logged somewhere, especially during unattended boot when stderr
# isn't normally logged anywhere. This path will be touched on every nginx
# start regardless of error log location configured here. See
# https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/147 for more info.
#
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
        worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
        #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        #keepalive_timeout  0;
        keepalive_timeout  65;

        #gzip  on;

        server {
                listen       80;
                server_name  localhost;

                #charset koi8-r;

                #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

                location / {
                        root   /usr/local/www/nginx;
                        index  index.html index.htm;
                }

                #error_page  404              /404.html;

                # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
                #
                error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
                        root   /usr/local/www/nginx-dist;
                }

                # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
                #
                #location ~ \.php$ {
                #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
                #}

                # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
                #
                #location ~ \.php$ {
                #    root           html;
                #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
                #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
                #    include        fastcgi_params;
                #}

                # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
                # concurs with nginx's one
                #
                #location ~ /\.ht {
                #    deny  all;
                #}
        }


        # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
        #
        #server {
        #    listen       8000;
        #    listen       somename:8080;
        #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

        #    location / {
        #        root   html;
        #        index  index.html index.htm;
        #    }
        #}


        # HTTPS server
        #
        #server {
        #    listen       443 ssl;
        #    server_name  localhost;

        #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
        #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

        #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        #    location / {
        #        root   html;
        #        index  index.html index.htm;
        #    }
        #}

}
```

I'm trying to get a basic setup to work, but nginx won't pass tests and won't start.  I am expecting it to start, naturally. My question is "how do I fix this?"  I've never run into this before on FreeBSD, or any other OS for that matter.

The pid is commented out because `rc.d` already points to the pid, as the error shows.  There is no permanent `nginx.pid` file in that location.

Comment: Also tried with user as `root`, group `admin`.

Comment: In FreeBSD there is no group admin by default, did you change something?

Comment: No, I said I tried it.  It is now serving http for some reason, but giving me the same errors.  I tried changing to root::admin to get around the permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

After installing Nginx do:

```
sysrc nginx_enable="YES"
```

Then to start the service

```
service nginx start
```

or

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/nginx start
```

Probably this may also work:

```
service nginx configtest
```

By default, the pid is in `/var/run/nginx.pid`

Later you can just do:

```
nginx -t
```

or

```
nginx -T
```

And should work with out printing any errors.

Comment: Turns out it started it self somehow this afternoon.  Even after a couple reboots, I couldn't see it working.  Had the `nginx_enable=YES` already in there, and the `service nginx start` wasn't working.  So it has progressed.  Thank you.

Comment: Try removing it, and later install `pkg install nginx-lite` should work out of the box.

Comment: Did that.  Even tried installing nginx-full, then back to nginx.  Using ports.  I've never seen a service, nor a pid file, and these errors.  I'll push through it some more.

Comment: Reinstalled the complete OS, 11.1-RC1, and got the default `nginx.conf`working.  Then replaced the server pointers, got the `nginx.pid` permissions errors.  Reinstalled the default `nginx.conf` and the permissions issues are remaining.

Comment: What do you mean with server pointers, check also output of `nginx -V` to se full paths

Comment: I was going to use `vhosts` or `virtual hosts` but those are Apache terms from what I remember.  It's serving a handful of domains.  Why do I need to see the paths?  Everything is in order.  Permissions are the issue.

Comment: is `nginx -V` printing something like `--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid` ? in any case try to use `ktrace` maybe that can give you a clue about what may be wrong, try to reproduce this pattern if possible and if necessary  file a bug report https://www.freebsd.org/support/bugreports.html

Comment: yes, --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid.  It just makes no sense that it needs permissions changed after I changed nginx.conf.  Anyway, fixed because I changed the nginx.conf.  Very strange.